# Updating GGPlot2 values in Shiny R through Date SliderInput

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a slider input in my Shiny app. It appears fine in the app but I am struggling to pass the values into server function. I am unable to create that interactivity for it to change when someone plays with the Slide. Thanks

My Data looks like this:

[Snippet of data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGdoK.png)

R Code as Below:

```js
testdfall <- testdf
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

testdfall <- data.frame(date = c('2020-03-01', '2020-03-02','2020-03-03', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-05', '2020-03-06', '2020-03-07','2020-03-08', '2020-03-09'), 
                    ptppAll = c('0.2', '4.14', '1.2', '0.2', '0.4', '0', '0.6', '0.6', '7.27'), 
                    mAverage = c('', '', '', '0.962', '10.2', '1.47', '2.06', '2.10', '2.10')) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "Areas", label="Choose your Areas", choices = c("Barn"="Barn",
                                                                                "Ham"="Ham",
                                                                                "Donc"="Donc",
                                                                                "Field"="Field",
                                                                                "All Areass"="AllAreass"),
                selected = "AllAreass", multiple = TRUE),
    
    
    sliderInput("slider", label = h4("Slider Range"),
                min = as.Date("2020-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
                max = as.Date("2020-12-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
                value=as.Date(c("2020-12-01","2020-05-01")),
                timeFormat="%Y-%m-%d")
    
    
  ),
  mainPanel(
 
  plotOutput(outputId="mAveragePlot"),

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  #Attempt at creating variable for values from user interaction
  date = renderPrint({ input$slider })

  output$mAveragePlot<- renderPlot({
    if ((input$Areas=="AllAreass")){
      ggplot(data=testdfall, aes(x=date)) +
        geom_line(aes(y=mAverage),colour="red") +
        geom_line(aes(y=ptppAll ))+
        ggtitle("Daily Cases with Moving Average") +
        labs(x="Date", y="Positive Tests Per 100,000 Population") +
        scale_x_date(breaks = "2 day")+ #displays every 2 days. If need to change, put "3 day" for label every 3 days or "month" for each month +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
        labs(colour='test Areas Name')
    }else {
      ggplot(data=testdf%>% filter(AreasName == input$Areas), aes(x=date)) + 
        geom_line(aes(y=mAverage, group=AreasName, colour=AreasName),colour="red") +
        geom_line(aes(y=ptpp ,group=AreasName, colour=AreasName),colour="black")+
        ggtitle("Daily Cases Per test Areas") + 
        labs(x="Date", y="Positive Tests Per 100,000 Population") +
        scale_x_date(breaks = "2 day")+ #displays every 2 days. If need to change, put "3 day" for label every 3 days or "month" for each month +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
        labs(colour='test Areas Name')
    }
  })
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You don't seem to have any outputs that depend on your slider.  That's probably why changing your slider has no effect on your outputs.  What do you want the slider to do?  Change the time axis of the graph, perhaps?  Maybe look at `dateRangeInput` as a more natural way of doing this?

Comment: Hi @Limey , thanks. I understand that I don't have a dependant output - I wasn't sure how to do it. Yes, I would like the graph to reflect the date range chosen. Thanks for the 'dateRangeInput' but I think the actual slider is preferred for aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.  Here's a MWE demonstrating the functionality you want.  I missed the test data in your question (sorry), so I used a variation of the `faithful` dataset that is included with tidyverse (and yes, I deliberately misinterpreted one of the columns so that I got a reasonable range of dates to play with).

The reason that your attempt didn't work is that `renderPrint` creates an output object, which is intended to appear in the GUI, not be used in your server logic.  The reason it didn't appear in the GUI is that you didn't define a corresponding output object in you `ui` function.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

data <- faithful %>% mutate(eruptionTime=lubridate::now() + lubridate::dhours(cumsum(waiting)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider", label = "Date Range",
              min = min(data$eruptionTime),
              max = max(data$eruptionTime),
              value=c(min(data$eruptionTime),max(data$eruptionTime)),
              timeFormat="%Y-%m-%d"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    data %>% 
      ggplot() +
        geom_point(aes(x=eruptionTime, y=eruptions)) +
        coord_cartesian(xlim=input$slider)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I recommend using `coord_cartesian` to change the axis limits rather than the seemingly more obvious `xlim`, (or `ylim`) because the latter *exclude* data before creating the plot, whereas `coord_cartesian` first creates the plot and then "zooms" the viewport to the required area.  The distinction doesn't matter here, but it would if you were doing any model fitting or smoothing: using `xlim` would give misleading results.

Comment: Oh great, thank you so much! Simple and worked just fine!  Appreciated! You have my up vote!